# Hibernate/JPA persistence.xml leads to SAXParseException when deploying to Jetty as WAR

Tags: hibernate, jpa, maven, jetty, jpa-2.0

I'm having trouble getting an application running on Jetty.

If I run the app using the maven jetty plugin i.e.

```
mvn jetty:run
```

It all runs fine.  If I package the app as a war and try to deploy to a Jetty server manually I get the exception

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value '2.0' of attribute 'version' of element 'persistence' is not valid with respect to the corresponding attribute use. Attribute 'version' has a fixed value of '1.0'.
```

It I try and deploy to Jetty using

```
mvn jetty:run-war
```

I get the same error.

The hibernate/JPA dependancies my app is using are

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.7.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm confused why it works when running with jetty:run and not when deployed as a war.  I've tried various versions of both Jetty 7 and 8 with no luck.

Thanks.

Can anyone spot anything wrong with what I'm trying?

EDIT: Heres the persistence.xml

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>            
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>            
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have older (before JPA2 compatibility) version of hibernate in your classpath before 2.0 compatible libraries? It can also come via some dependency.

Comment: Not that I can see.  I've searched through every JAR file in the WEB-INF/libs folder of the WAR and the only reference to anything JPA 1 is  the file org/hibernate/ejb/persistence_1_0.xsd in hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.3.Final.jar which shouldn't be being used as the persistence.xml is referencing persistence_2_0.xsd

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  Turns out a jersey-spring maven dependancy was bringing in Spring 2.5 stuff which was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using maven and the open-jpa maven plugin, be aware to put in the correct version

If your using this one

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>**/entities/*.class,**/entities/masterdata/*.class</includes>
                <excludes>**/entities/*Enum.class</excludes>
                <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>

                <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enhancer</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
                    <!-- set the version to be the same as the level in your runtime -->
                    <version>1.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

this will lead to the version error. it should be:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>**/entities/*.class,**/entities/masterdata/*.class</includes>
                <excludes>**/entities/*Enum.class</excludes>
                <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>

                <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enhancer</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
                    <!-- set the version to be the same as the level in your runtime -->
                    <version>2.2.0*</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```